# string operations and odd results

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2012

first post so my apologies if I break protocol.

I'm working on a silly program for school and I have the following code.

```
cout << "//Dictionary Program//\n\n";
cout << "Enter a command:\n's' - to search for a pattern at the beginning\n";
cout << "'e' - to search for a pattern at the end\n";
cout << "'c' - to search for a pattern anywhere in the word\n";

//Gather user input.
cout << "Please enter a command ('q' to quit): ";
cin >> userCommand;

cmdCheck = userCommand.find("secq");

while(cmdCheck < 0 || userCommand.length() > 1){
    cout << "Please enter a valid command\n";
    cin >> userCommand;
    cmdCheck = userCommand.find("secq");

}
```

This is driving a menu and I am trying to validate the input. It should be one letter, and one of the following "secq"

1. I am having a terrible time with the string.find() in the immediate window. I end up with CXX0047: Error: argument list does not match a function. Which I don't understand at all because I am using it elsewhere.
2. The while condition is not being nice to me. When I give the program a "v" it ends up inside the block like it should, but then I give it an "s" where the cmdCheck should evaluate to 0, but it gives a -1 and stays inside the block.
3. Lastly, I coded around another error with the cmdCheck but I had that in the while condition and it was not working either. `while(userCommand.find("secq") < 0 ...`

My inital thought was a problem with the input buffer but when I look at the userCmd variable in the Locals window I have a character array of size 1. There is only the letter and no junk from the buffer (as far as I can tell)

I know I could just tie a bunch of || together with each command but this is a bit more elegant in my opinion. I looked at my final last year and my conditionals were ugly. It's more of a matter of principle at this point.

Comment: how is userCommand declared?
is it a string?

Comment: userCommand is a string. cmdCheck is int

Comment: try re-redeading documentation for std::string::find

Comment: Maybe you were looking for [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)?

Comment: Well, at the very least should string.find("secq") return a 0 if userCommand is an "s" or 1 if userCommand is an "e"?

Comment: @neagoegab I as searching the input for the for the validation string. Is that what you were getting at when you wanted me to read the documentation? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `userCommand.find("secq")` tries to find the string `"secq"` in `userCommand`. From the sounds of it, you actually want to do the exact opposite, i.e., find the `userCommand` in the string `"secq"`:

```
std::string::size_type cmdCheck = std::string("secq").find(userCommand);
while (cmdCheck == std::string::npos) {
    ...
}
```

Also note that `std::string` doesn't return an `int`. Instead it returns a `std::string::size_type`. This may be a `typedef` for `int` but it may also be a `typedef` for a different integer type. If the string being passed to `find()` can't be found, `std::string::npos` is returned. The exact value for this constant is also not defined so you are best off comparing to this constant instead of making any assumptions.

Comment: Oh man. Can I delete this post? That was exactly it. I had the items in backwards.

`const string CMDLIST = "secq";`
and
`cmdCheck = CMDLIST.find(userCommand);`

Thanks everyone! I feel silly!

Answer (score 1):

Take input using getline in a string.

```
getline (cin, userCommand) ;
```

If the input is one letter, take it in a single char. If you insist on taking it in a string, use its first index to check.

Comment: cmdCheck still evaluates to -1.

Comment: if the input is one letter, why are you taking it in a string?

Comment: I'm comparing it to a string and not a char array and I was hoping to stay in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `userCommand` is an `std::string`. Since the command is supposed to be a single character, use a `char` instead of a string. Then just use the value as the argument in a `switch` statement, with appropriate cases for the valid characters and a `default` case that gives an error message.

Comment: I _could_ do that. I'm actually more interested in what I have done wrong here because I'm thinking it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a loop like this would be more appropriate:

```
char result;
std::cout << "Your command: ";

for (std::string line; ; )
{
    if (!(std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::cerr << "Fatal error: Unexpected end of input!\n";
        std::exit(1); 
    }

    if (line.size() == 1 && line.find_first_of("secq") == 0)
    {
        result = line[0];
        break;
    }

    std::cout << "Sorry, I did not understand. Please say again: ";
}

std::cout << "Thank you! You said, '" << result << "'\n";
```

Now if the loop breaks, `result` will contain the user input.